# What is the UDP Send Rate?

Tags: udp

Does UDP send all packets as soon as they become available as opposed to TCP's monitored approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP has congestion control, UDP does not as it is connection-less.

But your question covers multiple issues: does sending a message cause it to be immediately delivered?  Not always, on high performance networking hardware you will find Interrupt Coalescing which causes the operating system to delay passing messages to the hardware in order to optimise high throughput situations.  Some further explanation here:

http://blogs.informatica.com/perspectives/index.php/2009/06/10/how-does-interrupt-coalescing-affect-low-latency-high-performance-messaging/